# Switch to results Component `onSubmit` a search form in react hooks using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Hi I have a scenario where I put a search bar on the top nav so a user can search from anywhere in the app. How to do I switch to the results component once the user submits the search form? Here's my search component that populates the global state with search results but I can't manage to switch the view to the results component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { StateContext } from '../../StateContext';

import './SearchBar.scss';

import sprite from '../../assets/icons/sprite.svg';

function SearchBar() {
    const [state, setState] = useContext(StateContext);
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
    const [bookName, setBookName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${bookName}`)
            .then((res) => {
                let book_list = res.data.items;
                setState({
                    book_list: book_list,
                    heading: 'Search Results'
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, [bookName]);

    const findBook = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setBookName(userInput);
    };

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setUserInput(e.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <form className='searchbar' onSubmit={findBook}>
            <input
                type='search'
                className='searchbar__input'
                placeholder='Search for a book'
                value={userInput}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <button className='searchbar__button'>
                <svg className='searchbar__icon'>
                    <use xlinkHref={`${sprite}#icon-search`} />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Here's how I'm handling routing:

```
import React from 'react';

import Nav from './components/Nav/Nav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Books from './containers/Books';

import Book from './containers/Book';

import { ContextController } from './StateContext';

function App() {
    return (
        <ContextController>
            <Router>
                <div className='app'>
                    <Nav />
                    <main>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Books} />
                            <Route exact path='/book/:id' component={Book} />
                        </Switch>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </ContextController>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dedicated route for search results, try this in your `ContextController`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// later

const history = useHistory();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (state?.book_list?.length > 0) {
    history.push('/search-results');
  }
}, [state]);
```

Also, it is important to note that the `Router` should be on top of your `Data Context`;
Because if you want to access the history from the a tree, it needs to be wrapped in a `Router`, or else it will return undefined as a value for `history`

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-euler-8bwhr)

Comment: `TypeError: history.push is not a function`

Comment: what version of react router dom are you using ?

Comment: version `^5.1.2`

Comment: I figured out your problem, you need to move the router before the ContextProvider

Comment: I'm not sure about this you mean wrap my app with `Router` before I wrap it with `ContextProvider` ? That does not seem to work.

Comment: Actually its working; i updated with a working codesandbox

Comment: I added also the explanation why you get the undefined, it s because your context isn't in a tree in which there is a `history`

Comment: That worked, cheers a bunch. The issue was wrapping the `DataProvider` with `Router`